# High Graphics 3D Game Development for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, graphics

I have good experience with the iPhone development tools and making apps with window based applications and stuff. I am now trying to make an awesome 3D game, which is an area I have never tried out.

I am very interested in learning about the development of `"INFINITY BLADE"` and I am very curious to know how it was developed and how they were able to develop it with so much detail.

I had already looked at links like [iPhone 3D Engines](http://www.neverreadpassively.com/2009/03/review-of-iphone-3d-engines.html), but it seems outdated.

1. Where is a good place to start  for learning HIGH Performance 3D games for iPhone / iPad ?
2. Could you share any tips on the development life cycle for the 3D Games ??
3. Tools used for making high quality 3D images for the creative side of iPhone Development ? And resources on the creative side ?
4. Could you share the game development life cycle for a particular app , or perhaps your comments on the development of Infinity  Blade ?

Comment: Maybe this fits better on [gamedev.stackexchange.com](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Oops. I did not know it existed... (anyways..)  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never actually used it so I can't give too much information on it, but you could try looking at cocos2d's lesser known sibling, cocos3d. That would probably be the most cost effective way to learn how to do some 3d game programming in obj-c.

http://brenwill.com/cocos3d/

But if you're looking to bang a game out quickly and learn a good amount about game development, Unity3D might be the best option. They have a few really good hands on tutorials.

http://unity3d.com/support/resources/tutorials/

I might be wrong, but I think Unity might require the use of C# under mono, in which case I'm not sure if that would be something you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a full answer, but I decided to post it anyways.

Infinity blade was written using unreal engine 3, which recently (or not so recently) got an export to iPhone option. Unreal engine is the same engine used for games such as gears of war. I'm assuming that the actual difficulty of getting high quality graphics to run well on the iPhone was handled by unreal engine. As for making the graphics, I'm sure they hired a (bunch of) 3D artists. You can get the UDK for unreal off of their website, which allows you to start learning with it. The only caveat is the cost of the engine when you actually want to release a game.

Comment: How is this related to objective-c ?

Comment: It's not, it addresses the question of Infinity Blade's origin and a good place to start for learning High performance 3d games.

Comment: I see. Thats awesome.  How do you think is the development for say.. a game of 3D chess or a pool ?

Comment: That's probably simpler; I would think such games use their own 3D engine, maybe with collision scripts for the pool. If you looked, you might find something on github or the like, though.